# an access violation writing location error the third time when calling a python function in c code

Tags: python, c++

I am coding in c to solve a question. In the c code, I need to call a self-defined python to solve a equation. I am able to call the python function for twice time, however when i call the third time, I get an error:**"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FEDF8A4E0C(multiarray.cp35-win_amd64.pyd) in Project.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000000000000A."** It is very strange because in the first and second time, **I can call the function successfully and if I independently call the function with the parameters used in the third time, the function can run very well.** However, if I try to do the work continuously, it causes the exception above. I have seen a similar question '*C's Python API: Calling python function 2X causes Access violation writing location*' in STACKOVERFLOW, however, there is no answer for that problem.

```
PyObject* pRet = PyEval_CallObject(pv, args);
```

The c code above is the place where causing the exception when calling the python function the third time. The whole process calling the python function is described more clearly below.

Here comes the python function first

```
from sympy import *
init_printing(use_unicode=True)
def evaluate_dH(eps,bmax,H,B_H1,B_H2):
    x=symbols("x")
    expr=eps*(x-bmax)**2*x**(H+2)-(H+2)*x*B_H1+(H+1)*B_H2
    result=solve(expr,x)#result is a list type
```

When solving out the equation, I used two condition that ">bmax" and "not a complex" to find the value in '*result*' I need. the final is only one. Thus,

```
return result[0]
```

Second, here comes the calling process in c code.
Firstly, "double find_dH" is a c function I used in my main function.

```
double find_dH
(....)
{
double B_H2 = findBH(region, vecp_vertex, H + 2, index);
double B_H1 = findBH(region, vecp_vertex, H + 1, index);
double eps = 0.01;
double bmax = findbmax(region, vecp_vertex);
Py_Initialize();
PyObject *pModule = NULL;
PyRun_SimpleString("import sys");
PyRun_SimpleString("sys.path.append('./')");
pModule = PyImport_ImportModule("evaluate_dH");
PyObject* pv = PyObject_GetAttrString(pModule, "evaluate_dH");
PyObject* args = PyTuple_New(5);
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 0, Py_BuildValue("d", double(eps)));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 1, Py_BuildValue("d", double(bmax)));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 2, Py_BuildValue("i", H));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 3, Py_BuildValue("d", double(B_H1)));
PyTuple_SetItem(args, 4, Py_BuildValue("d", double(B_H2)));
PyObject* pRet = PyEval_CallObject(pv, args);
double result = PyFloat_AsDouble(pRet);
Py_Finalize();
return result;
}
```

**Here is the place where causing the exception:**"Unhandled exception at 0x00007FEDF8A4E0C(multiarray.cp35-win_amd64.pyd) in Project.1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x000000000000000A.". But, "PyEval_CallObject(pv, args)" works well before the third time.

```
PyObject* pRet = PyEval_CallObject(pv, args);
```

I guess the exception is caused by the reason that:
1. import module 'sympy' multitimes
2. no free for those 'PyObject's in the calling process after each calling.

thanks for your reading and answers!

Comment: Can you create a single [mcve]?  Lots of little snippets makes it impossible to tell how everything fits together.

Comment: Not related to the actual problem, but do you really want to remove the elements *below* maximum? `elif abs(i)<bmax and abs(i)>-bmax :` Additionally, the and part is totally obsolete: abs is positive, so provided bmax is positive as well, second check *always* succeeds - and if bmax is negative, first one already fails - *always*...

Comment: There is some null pointer involved (`x = nullptr; x->member = ...` with member having an offset of 10 to get address 0xa...). Have you checked each tuple member for not being `nullptr`? Have you tried debugging into?

Comment: @MilesBudnek thanks. I just worry if people can understand the question clearly, I will try to make it more brief

Comment: @Aconcagua thanks. It is a mistake about remove the elements below maximum and I have fixed it. But it is not the main problem. Referring to 'the null pointer' and 'each tuple member' you mentioned, what do you mean specifically about the pointer and the tuple? The result obtained by 'evaluate_dH' is a list actually and do you mean I need to check it?

Comment: @Aconcagua when I run the c code alone only once by using the arguments used in the third time, I can obtain the same answer as the result got in python3.6 directly

Comment: What if any of the calls to Py_BuildValue returned NULL (as in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html)? (By the way, do you know that you can construct an entire tuple from Py_BuldValue?)

Comment: @Aconcagua  thanks. I have figured out the problem. According to Python’s documents, multi-time Py_Initialize() may cause some bugs about memory. Thus, when I place the initialize in the main function, there is no problem.

Answer (score 0):

Working in C++, I was getting a similar error when calling

```
PyObject* pValue = Py_BuildValue("(s)", param);
```

To solve the issue I copied the string into a char*

```
PyObject* getPythonValueString(string param)
{
    char* paramVal = new char[param.length() + 1];
    strcpy(paramVal, param.c_str());
        
    PyObject* pValue = Py_BuildValue("(s)", paramVal);
    PyErr_Print();

    // Remember to clean up.
    delete[] paramVal;

    return pValue;
}
```